# Firebase Advanced Dictionary Search

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**I have many Telegram Keyboards in my Firebase**, and I Want to Have an Advance Dictionery Search for Childs of `Keyboards`, I Mean in Secend Level Deep, that the user entered,
Forexample user entered `rock`, I want to get each Keyboards contain rock at the **begin** or **middle** or at the **end**, in This Example I have 3 Keyboards: `morning`, `rock` and `rocky`.

```
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/rock');  //keyboard 1
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/morning');  //keyboard 2
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/rocky');  //keyboard 3
```

How Can I get and `console.log`: `rock` and `rocky` when user typed `rock`?
My Problem 90% Solved By @rymdmaskin But Advance Dictionery Search Still is Open.
`equalTo` and `startAt` and `endAt` Not Work, I need Something like `contain`, Someone Said to use Elastic Search (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/01/queries-part-2-advanced-searches-with.html)

**Structure:**
[image]

**Rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "Keyboards" : {
             ".indexOn": "Keyboards"
         }
  }
}
```

**Code:**

```
const ref = db.ref('/');
  ref.child('/').orderByChild('Keyboards').equalTo('rock').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    key = snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data.key);
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by put those in a string ? what are you trying to achieve really ? do you mean concatenate the content of each child node inside some kind of global var ?

Comment: Forexample I have a bank of books name, when a user typed `rock` in bot, The bot will send all the books including `rock` name, in this example i have rock and rocky and bot should send 2 message to user, rock and rocky have some chids: id, text, photo and .....

Comment: Firebase Database queries cannot search deeply nested properties. See my explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested I also suspect that you're dealing with a categorization problem, for which your data structure is not usable. See my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google's current method to do full text search seems to be syncing with either Algolia or BigQuery with Cloud Functions for Firebase.

Usage (elastic Search):
(https://medium.com/joolsoftware/extending-firebase-with-cloud-functions-elasticsearch-129fbbb951e0)

Answer (score 4):

If I got you right you would like to do something like this.

Structure:

```
- Keyboards
  - 0
    - name: "rocks"
    - children
      - 0: "id"
      - 1: "desc"
  - 1
    - name: "rocky"
    - children
      - 0: "id"
      - 1: "desc"
```

Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "Keyboards" : {
        "$key": {
           ".indexOn": "name"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Code:

```
const ref = db.ref('/');
  ref.child('Keyboards').orderByChild('name').equalTo('rocks').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    key = snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data.key);
    });
});
```

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: is your Structure same as my Structure?

Comment: I've renamed `childs` to `children `

Comment: I'm getting null in my terminal

Comment: I Don't want to update my data, my data is some books and i want to search and send to users, i will update my code now,

Comment: This will not work. The problem is your data structure. So if you want to make the code work you need of course to update your data.

Comment: Yeah sorry, not sure what you want to achieve either. And as @Orlandster says, I think it is better to restructure your data. Take a look at: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

Im not sure but you might be able to grab the values by: `orderByKey().startAt("rock")` with your previous code.

Also, the `indexOn` is just a warning, it is not an error, you could ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion was either change the structure on the database **or** use this query which seems to have solved the problem:

```
.orderByKey().startAt("rock")
```

I'm not so sure it will work for all your future cases tho because I think the query will start at *rock* but not end at *rocky* if you have more keyboards after *rocky*. I am just basing this on this source: [Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs&feature=youtu.be&t=5m52s)

[image]

Comment: I Have an another Function to getting Childs of rock and rocky and after a Convert, Sending Data to users.

Comment: my problem solved 95 % with your code, Is There Some thing like This: `.orderByKey().contain("rock")`  ? , and for dictionery search how should I implement?