# FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Keyboards" at / to your security rules for better performance

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

**Why I'm Getting This error?:**

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "Keyboards" at / to your security rules for better performance

I have many Telegram Keyboards in my Firebase
1: I want to Fix This Error. ✔️
2: I Want to get and Console.log `rock` and `rocky` when telegram user typed `rock`,

```
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/rock');  //keyboard 1
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/morning');  //keyboard 2
const ref = db.ref('Keyboards/rocky');  //keyboard 3
```

**Structure:** 
[image]

**Rules:**

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
      "Keyboards" : {
             ".indexOn": "Keyboards"
         }
  }
}
```

**Code:**

```
const ref = db.ref('/');
  ref.child('/').orderByChild('Keyboards').equalTo('rock').on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());
    key = snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
        console.log(data.key);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are running the same query multiple times and ordering by the same child each time: `Keyboards`. Firebase is telling you that you probably want to index this search, kinda like telling the database that your are going to do this often so be prepared that I am going to do this search often.

It is explained here: [Index your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data)

You can set up indexes under **Database -> Rules** in your project.

Comment: Maybe you set up the rules incorrectly. Hard to say without seeing your structure and rules.

Comment: I will start a +100 bounty for secend question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46410859/firebase-advanced-dictionary-search)